# how to send mail using Rest web service and json format data

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

Is it possible to send mail with  REST api in spring mvc application, I do a lot of research but I didn't find a tutorial that really explains what I need.

This is my `webconfig` class:

```
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean(name="mailSender")
    public MailSender javaMailService() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPort(587);
        javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
        javaMailSender.setUsername("email@gmail.com");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("password");
        Properties mailProperties = new Properties();
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "starttls");
        mailProperties.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(mailProperties);
        return javaMailSender;
    }

}
```

this is my service class :

```
@Transactional 
 @Service("mailServiceImpl")

public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {


private JavaMailSender emailSender;

@Autowired
public void setMailSender(JavaMailSender emailSender) { 
  this.emailSender = emailSender;
}
@Override
public void sendMail(final Mail mail) {
     try {
         emailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
             public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage)
                     throws Exception {
                 MimeMessageHelper message = new 
MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage,
                     false, "UTF-8");
             message.setFrom(mail.getFrom());
             message.addTo(mail.getTo());
             message.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
             message.setText(mail.getContent(), true);
         }
     });
 } catch (MailSendException e) {
     // your codes;
 }
 }
}
```

this is my class controller , whene I try to invoque my rest api I get error 
AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/OneToMany/Access_Denied] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

```
    @RestController
public class SendMailController  {


 MailService mailservice ;


 private JavaMailSender mailSender;


 @RequestMapping( value="/sendMail/", method =RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json", consumes="application/json")

 public @ResponseBody Mail add(@RequestBody Mail mail){
      mailservice.sendMail(mail);
    return mail;
 }


 }
```

Comment: What is your question? You only post a code without any other information like stacktrace. Add more details

Comment: I want to know how to send email using rest api , I'm new with spring mvc and web service . I tried with this code but it didn't work !

Comment: Why it didn't work, add the stacktrace then we can see what is going wrong

Comment: the error is : AVERTISSEMENT: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/OneToMany/Access_Denied] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'